# Javascript Event listeners not firing after recursive call to restart code

Tags: javascript

**Problem:**

The code for this memory game works until I click restart, which it does seem to do, but then the event listeners don't seem to work anymore. I have a hunch that this is due to the recursive call that I'm using to restart the game, but I don't understand why. Would anyone be able to please explain this to me?

After searching around, there are plenty of questions about event listeners not firing, but they are happening for reasons other than a recursive call.

**Code on JSFiddle**

[Memory Game on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JayS5/qmcuobdh/13/)

I'm sorry the JS is still so long, I've deleted and simplified as much as I dared without breaking the code.

```
cards = ['fa-diamond', 'fa-diamond',
'fa-paper-plane','fa-paper-plane',
'fa-anchor','fa-anchor',
'fa-bolt','fa-bolt',
'fa-cube', 'fa-cube',
'fa-bomb','fa-bomb',
'fa-leaf','fa-leaf',
'fa-bicycle','fa-bicycle'];

function initGame() {
    // shuffle the array
    const shuffledCards = shuffle(cards);

    // generates each li
    function generateCardHTML(card) {
      return `<li class="card" data-card=${card}><i class="fa ${card}"></i></li>`
    };

    function createHTML(){
      let deck = "";
      shuffledCards.forEach(function(card) {
        const genHTML = generateCardHTML(card);
        deck += genHTML;
      })
      return deck;
    };
  return createHTML();
};


// Selects the deck div to add all the cards, initialise the game

const gameDeck = document.querySelector('.deck');

gameDeck.innerHTML = initGame();


// Adding event listeners to each card and adding them to openCards array

const cardDeck = document.querySelectorAll('.card');

openCards = [];

cardDeck.forEach(function(card){
  card.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    card.classList.add('open', 'show');

    openingCards(card);
  });
});

// Check if cards match:

function openingCards(targetCard){
  if (targetCard.matches('.open.show')){
    openCards.push(targetCard);
    if (openCards.length == 2) {
      if (openCards[0].dataset.card == openCards[1].dataset.card) {
        openCards[0].classList.add("match");
        openCards[1].classList.add("match");

      };
          setTimeout(function() {
            openCards.forEach(function(card){
              card.classList.remove('open','show');
            })
            openCards = [];
          }, 1000);

    }
  }
};


// Shuffle function from http://stackoverflow.com/a/2450976
function shuffle(array) {
    var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

    while (currentIndex !== 0) {
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
        currentIndex -= 1;
        temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
        array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
        array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }

    return array;
}

// Code to select restart button and reinitialise the game

const restartBtn = document.querySelector(".fa-repeat");

restartBtn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
  console.log("Restart")
  gameDeck.innerHTML = initGame();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event listeners are attached to the old rendered DOM elements and not re-assigned to newly rendered elements when pressing restart...
So you have to re-attach event listeners everytime you restart the game...
Suggested solution would be to wrap *'Attach event part of code with a function'* and call this function everytime you init the game:

```
function attachEvents() {
    const cardDeck = document.querySelectorAll('.card');
    cardDeck.forEach(function(card){
        card.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        card.classList.add('open', 'show');

        openingCards(card);
        });
    });
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qmcuobdh/47/)

Comment: removeEventListener should also be called in the orphaned elements, otherwise anything captured by the closure of the listener functions will "leak"

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly :) @spender I didn't quite grasp what you said there. Could you explain what orphaned elements and closure of listener functions mean?

Comment: @Sanjay Where you `gameDeck.innerHTML = initGame();`, you're replacing existing HTML elements with new ones. The outgoing elements still have event handlers attached to them. These do not get automatically removed and prevent JS from garbage collecting anything that is referred to by these handlers. Before you overwrite the elements, call `removeEventListener` on them.